# Python3 неверно печатает элементы списка

Tags: python, django

Есть простой список:

```
tasks = [
    ['Зона 1:\rЗадача 1\r', True], 
    ['Зона 1:\rЗадача 2\r', True], 
    ['Зона 1:\rЗадача 3\r', True], 
    ['Зона 2: \rЗадача 1\r', True], 
    ['Зона 2: \rЗадача 2\r', True], 
    ['Зона 2: \rЗадача 3', True]
]
```

При выполнении следующих трех инструкций печатаются совсем разные данные:

```
for task in tasks:
    print(task)
    print(task[0])
    print(task[1])
```

Терминал:

```
['Зона 1:\rЗадача 1\r', True]
Задача 1
True
['Зона 1:\rЗадача 2\r', True]
Задача 2
True
['Зона 1:\rЗадача 3\r', True]
Задача 3
True
['Зона 2: \rЗадача 1\r', True]
Задача 1
True
['Зона 2: \rЗадача 2\r', True]
Задача 2
True
['Зона 2: \rЗадача 3', True]
Задача 3
True
```

Почему `print(task[0])` обрезает строку перед печатью? Может ли это как-то быть связано с тем, что я использую фреймворк Django или тем, что список - результат преобразования json-строки?

Comment: Так зачем Вы вставили возврат каретки `\r`? Может быть, Вам нужен был перевод строки `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему `print(task[0])` обрезает строку перед печатью?

Потому что в строке присутствует символ [возврата каретки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) `\r` (*CARRIAGE RETURN*).

***Описание из Wikipedia:***

> Перемещает позицию печати в крайнее левое положение (исходно — без
>   перевода на следующую строку).

---

Могу предположить, что Вы хотели использовать [перевод строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) `\n`.